# The problem of improper use of RAM in ASP.NET Core Web API project

Tags: memory-management, memory-leaks, asp.net-core-webapi, asp.net-core-6.0, dotmemory

I have an ASP.NET Core 6 Web API project.

When I'm running the project, my project takes about 2 GB of memory!

[image: memory diagnostic]

I found this problem in the dotMemory application:

[image: dotMemory's result]

There seems to be a problem with this part (Routing)

[image: Routing problem in dotMemory]

My project has some routes.

For example for every action, It has four routes.

[image: The result of an action in swagger]

They are defined like this:

[image: routing rules]

Where do you think the problem is, where did this memory problem come from and how should I solve it?

Comment: Hi Hamed, Can your project work with the latest .NET 6 or even .NET 7 previews? If so, I think it's worth checking out.

Comment: Hi, Thank you. I made a mistake. my project is .NET 6. I'll update that

Comment: Hello was the problem resolved? If you need any further assistance feel free to share your concern.

Comment: Hello. No, I have still this problem. I think the amount of RAM it got is unreasonable.